# Как автоматизировать запрос sql в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

помогите пожалуйста автоматизировать данный запрос в базу? Может тригером или событием. Либо чтоб при изменении dle_post делался запрос, либо через какое то время

```
REPLACE INTO `dlew_post` 
SELECT * FROM `dle_post`
1) 

    CREATE TABLE `dle_post` (
    
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    
    `autor` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    
    `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
    
    `short_story` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    
    `full_story` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    
    `xfields` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    
    `descr` varchar(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    
    `keywords` text NOT NULL,
    
    `category` varchar(190) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    
    `alt_name` varchar(190) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    
    `comm_num` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    
    `allow_comm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    
    `allow_main` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    
    `approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    
    `fixed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    
    `allow_br` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    
    `symbol` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    
    `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    
    `metatitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

2) Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - 5.6.43

3) 

    INSERT INTO `dlew_post` (`id`, `autor`, `date`, `short_story`, `full_story`, `xfields`, `title`, `descr`, `keywords`, `category`, `alt_name`, `comm_num`, `allow_comm`, `allow_main`, `approve`, `fixed`, `allow_br`, `symbol`, `tags`, `metatitle`) VALUES
    
    (50, 'Anatoly', '2021-03-26 23:19:09', 'Bruce Wayne est déterminé à faire en sorte que le sacrifice ultime de Superman ne soit pas vain. Pour cela, avec l\\\'aide de Diana Prince, il met en place un plan pour recruter une équipe de métahumains afin de protéger le monde d\\\'une menace apocalyptique imminente. La tâche s\\\'avère plus difficile qu\\\'il ne l\\\'imaginait, car chacune des recrues doit faire face aux démons de son passé, et les surpasser, pour se rassembler et former une ligue de héros sans précédent. Désormais unis, Batman, Wonder Woman, Aquaman, Cyborg et Flash réussiront-ils à sauver la planète de Steppenwolf, DeSaad, Darkseid et de leurs terribles intentions ?', 'Bruce Wayne est déterminé à faire en sorte que le sacrifice ultime de Superman ne soit pas vain. Pour cela, avec l\\\'aide de Diana Prince, il met en place un plan pour recruter une équipe de métahumains afin de protéger le monde d\\\'une menace apocalyptique imminente. La tâche s\\\'avère plus difficile qu\\\'il ne l\\\'imaginait, car chacune des recrues doit faire face aux démons de son passé, et les surpasser, pour se rassembler et former une ligue de héros sans précédent. Désormais unis, Batman, Wonder Woman, Aquaman, Cyborg et Flash réussiront-ils à sauver la planète de Steppenwolf, DeSaad, Darkseid et de leurs terribles intentions ?', 'poster|2021-03/825c8476245958121249cd684418a3dd_image.jpeg||year|2021||duration|242||sound|French||quality|HDRIP||country|United States of America||director|Charles Roven, Christopher Nolan, Emma Thomas, Dody Dorn, Ben Affleck, Kim McGarrity, Frank Miller||actors|Ben Affleck, Henry Cavill, Gal Gadot, Jason Momoa, Ezra Miller, Ray Fisher, Amy Adams||supervideo|j19b4coa415x||ninjastream|76VAqLXGzmoqy||vudeo|whra5ygmx24z||streamtape|YWP7qVRj7wTvx3A||youtube|lTnRSMfFvu4||bck|2021-03/825c8476245958121249cd684418a3dd_image.jpeg||scrins|2021-03/1ed5375e5498e63b1d69607d7167108d_image.jpeg,2021-03/634144cc1940a5f5d013bba05badd8ee_image.jpeg,2021-03/d56dca63e39050f5ed88df515dac85b9_image.jpeg,2021-03/1e46e17e711f648af3da4793fd084b45_image.jpeg,2021-03/92185eb2a1445c8a51db1fde03fac0bd_image.jpeg||trama|https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/791373-zack-snyder-s-justice-league', 'Zack Snyder\\\'s Justice League', 'Bruce Wayne est déterminé à faire en sorte que le sacrifice ultime de Superman ne soit pas vain. Pour cela, avec l\'aide de Diana Prince, il met en place un plan pour recruter une équipe de métahumains afin de protéger le monde d\'une menace apocalyptique imminente. La tâche s\'avère plus difficile', 'Zack Snyder\'s Justice League en streaming, Zack Snyder\'s Justice League streaming hdss, Zack Snyder\'s Justice League streaming vf, Zack Snyder\'s Justice League streaming complet vf, Zack Snyder\'s Justice League hdss, Zack Snyder\'s Justice League hdssfilm', '1,3,10,26', 'zack-snyders-justice-league-en-streaming', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Z', 'Zack Snyder\'s Justice League', 'Film Zack Snyder\'s Justice League en streaming complet VF | HDss'),

4) При вставке записей в dle_post, должна идти запись в dlew_post

5) Не нужны никакие

Просто при появлении записей в dle_post, копировать в dlew_post, все идентично, кроме прификса dle, dlew
```

Comment: Чтобы любое изменение данных одной таблицы инициировало копирование **ВСЕХ** данных этой таблицы в другую таблицу? Вы точно этого хотите?

Comment: Да либо так, либо когда запись добавлялась в dle_post, оно и добавлялось в dlew_post

Comment: Вы пишете, что хотите ВСЕ записи копировать во вторую таблицу, и старые, и новые... А вовсе даже не одну свежедобавленную. А так - да, триггер. Только копировать надо `WHERE dle_post.id = NEW.id`.

Comment: Какие настройки тригера должны быть и запрос? чтоб все хорошо проходило?

Comment: 1) Выложите полные CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц. 2) Укажите точную версию MySQL. 3) Покажите пример запроса, изменяющего первую таблицу, и запись, которая должна быть при этом помещена во вторую таблицу. 4) Уточните, копирование должно выполняться при: вставке, изменении, в обоих случаях? 5) Нужны ли какие-то действия при удалении записи из первой таблицы?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/zOfQIaFsMWfTdw
вот здесь файл, как просили

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте информацию непосредственно в вопрос (с правильным форматированием), а не в файл, мало того что непонятно где, так к тому же способный в любой момент оттуда испариться.

Comment: отредактировал ворос

Comment: 1) Ваша таблица не содержит уникальных индексов (кстати, почему? даже первичного индекса нет) - так что REPLACE не имеет смысла. Просто INSERT. 2) *Версия клиента базы данных* Я просил версию сервера БД, а не библиотеки доступа к серверу. Выполните `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: 5.6.51-cll-lve
я когда выполняю выше мой запрос, все хорошо работает. Но мне автоматом хотелось бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_copy_new_row
AFTER INSERT
ON dle_post
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `dlew_post` (`id`, `autor`, `date`, `short_story`, `full_story`, `xfields`, 
                         `title`, `descr`, `keywords`, `category`, `alt_name`, `comm_num`, 
                         `allow_comm`, `allow_main`, `approve`, `fixed`, `allow_br`, 
                         `symbol`, `tags`, `metatitle`) 
VALUES (NEW.`id`, NEW.`autor`, NEW.`date`, NEW.`short_story`, NEW.`full_story`, 
        NEW.`xfields`, NEW.`title`, NEW.`descr`, NEW.`keywords`, NEW.`category`, 
        NEW.`alt_name`, NEW.`comm_num`, NEW.`allow_comm`, NEW.`allow_main`, NEW.`approve`, 
        NEW.`fixed`, NEW.`allow_br`, NEW.`symbol`, NEW.`tags`, NEW.`metatitle`);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3d8f6ae89a7640cf0ceeac6a1cf92e5

Comment: MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). (Запрос занял 0.0237 сек.)

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков Fiddle добавил. Всё работает. А у Вас не работает, скорее всего, по причине бардака с квотированием кавычек (я замаялся исправлять Ваш INSERT...).

Comment: а зачем всю структуру писать? Поля то одинаковые

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков А затем, что `NEW` - это вот ни разу не таблица. А первичного ключа или хотя бы какого завалящего уникального индекса, к которому можно было бы прицепиться, в Вашей структуре - нет.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ugkfdAq.png
вот такие настройки у меня

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RCwOVGF.png
вот структура, вроде id первичный же?

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков *вроде id первичный же?* Кто из нас помещал в текст своего вопроса "полные CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц"? Вот у него и спрашивайте, куда он дел PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: я делал экспорт таблицы, может оттуда пропало это)

Comment: Вам нужен VPS для выполнения запросов с правами суперпользователя.
Может как то в файл этот запрос сделать и запускать кроном?